# Form with two pages [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, mailer

I made a form that works with mesh.
The form of class A works but I created a new class B still in form, it is precisely the continuation. My problem is that mailer managed to retrieve the information with the class A but the B I can not communicate. Do you have a solution to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. I added the final in the class except that it is necessary to leave the class for it to work.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';

//Formulaire page 1 rattachement de l'envoie par e-mail
final _recipientController = TextEditingController();
final _nomController = TextEditingController();
final _prenomController = TextEditingController();

//Formulaire page 2
final _formKey2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _adresseController = TextEditingController();
final _codepostalController = TextEditingController();
final _siretController = TextEditingController();
final _nomEntrepriseController = TextEditingController();
```